# Compensation for missed connection due to delay with same airline but separate bookings

Tags: airlines, connecting-flights, missed-flights

Long story short, I had to fly from A (in Spain) to C (in the UK) and I booked two separate flights with the same budget airline, so the actual route was A (Spain) -> B (UK) -> C (UK).

The first flight was delayed by 90 minutes, which means that I was unable to catch the second one (the layover time was around an hour and a half) and had to buy another ticket for the following day (with another airline).

I googled a lot and found mixed responses. Is there any chance I can get a refund for my second flight? I will obviously ask them but I'm unsure what my best course of action is.

Comment: Part of the context would be whether or not you tried to get the budget airline to re-book the second flight for you, since it was their fault you missed the connection.

Comment: Why did you not book it as a "single flight with layover"?  Was there a cost reason?

Comment: @EBlake It's their fault the first flight was delayed, but they do *not* have any responsibility for connections they did not set up for you in the first place.

Comment: @Harper this airline does not offer actual connections, I think the proper term is point-to-point, or something similar

Comment: @Harper Budget airlines in Europe tend not to offer layovers - precisely so that they are not liable for the costs of any delays like this.

Comment: Did you take any travel insurance?  This might cover you....

Comment: @UKMonkey that'd be nice... Unfortunately, no

Comment: @MartinBonner That's it, then. OP got cheaper seats, declining transfer protection in exchange for a better price.  [Albert Brooks tried it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf2q0HemaFs)....

Comment: If this were the US I'd be saying file a chargeback with the credit card company. The air carrier will not be able to explain how a delay created by them caused the customer to lose.

Comment: @Joshua the chargeback would fail when the air carrier pointed out the customer booked separate, unconnnected tickets.  The bank will understand that.  No carrier is liable for domino-effect consequences of late running.

Comment: @Joshua and furthermore, the credit card company and/or airline may take legal steps against you for attempts to defraud them, and rightly so.

Comment: How was the booking arranged? Contrary to the answers below, I am aware of a UK court case that decided in the case of a budget airline, although it was two separate tickets, it was sold as a single transaction and should therefore be regarded as a connecting flight. I can look it up if it's relevant.

Comment: @Calchas the two flights were booked separately (two different transactions), so I'm afraid there's not much to do

Comment: Just for reference, what was the cost of the two tickets, vs what would have been the cost with a full-fare airline which did offer connections? Also, what would have been the cost of travel insurance incl. missed connection insurance? (missed connection insurance < n hours is generally not covered by travel insurance policies by default, it's an optional add-on. On the occasions I've looked into this, it's not economical, it's better to book the full-fare airline if missing the connection would be a major problem, esp. if the next flight is 6-24 hours later).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

***No***, you're not entitled to any compensation.  You chose to book separate flights, so the airline did not guarantee your connection and the risk is fully on you.

In addition, because your flight was delayed by less than 3 hours, you're not entitled to EU's delay compensation either.

Comment: You are not entitled to compensation for your missed connection, because you **didn't have a connection to miss**.

Comment: @JörgWMittag For a specific, limited definition of “connection”. From the traveller’s perspective (and in common parlance), there was definitely a connection (and it was missed). That this connection isn’t recognised by the airline is little solace. To claim that “[OP] didn’t have a connection” is pure newspeak.

Comment: @KonradRudolph in oldspeak however, one could say that they have a connection since by definition of the word connection, it is one. In the airline's terms however, it isn't a connecting flight since it's not made in one booking

Comment: @codeninja Right, in the *airline’s terms*. And while this is relevant for the purpose of the compensation, it’s simply inaccurate to suggest that a connection in the context of travelling always (or even *usually*) refers to a contractually agreed connecting flight. On the contrary, if I need to catch a bus after a train, *that’s a connection*. If I catch a cab, that’s still a connection. This usage is ubiquitous. And Jörg’s comment pretends that this usage doesn’t exist, or is somehow less legitimate.

Comment: IIUC, a flight booking is a connection if it's under a single reservation number. Which wasn't the case here. Why the OP didn't book under a single reservation, I don't understand.

Answer (score 18):

You [might be entitled to a refund of the Air Passenger Duty](http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/holidays/article-3723398/How-claim-tax-ticket-miss-flight.html). This won't be very much, and some airlines impose a fee or minimum amount for this refund that could make it completely pointless. Check your airline's policy to see what conditions apply.

Comment: Did not know about this, interesting. I'll have a look

Answer (score 11):

As jpatokal already said, you're out of luck.

Let me add a different perspective. It costs the airline money to guarantee that they will get you to the final destination. Some, such as Ryanair, have therefore decided not to offer tickets between destinations which are not directly connected. This helps them push the ticket prices very low, but you risk experiencing issues with (not really) connecting flights in case of a delay.

If you want to have a "guaranteed" connection with this airline, you can try booking with Kiwi, who take care of getting you on another flight instead of the airline which is unwilling to do so. They accept the risk of losing money if there is a delay and they have to pay for another ticket out of their pocket, so their tickets won't be as cheap as the ones you get when booking directly with the budget airline. In a sense, they are not only a booking agency, but an insurance company as well.

That being said, they do not really guarantee that they will get you to the final destination, but they have a very good incentive to do so if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Jpatokal's answer is fairly definitive and correct. I'm sure the answer is no. A UK internal flight (2nd leg) is also of a short distance, so for any similar situation the compensation is limited.

A site I've used for advise in the past, details the rules around compensation and offers guidance on how to obtain it (usually at no cost), just in case anyone sees a similar situation:

https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/travel/flight-delays/

PS: I've no affiliation to the site, it's associated with Martin Lewis, whom is a financial expert whom has his own TV show on ITV (in the UK). I thought it to be useful in case someone wants to read more regarding the rules regarding compensation or have a very similar issue.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. If jpatokal's answer is good, you should upvote it rather than posting an endorsement as a separate answer. Also, a new member posting a short answer with a link tends to raise spam flags, so I would [edit] the post to indicate if you have any affiliation with it. I strongly encourage you  to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.